# jspdf no hace el salto de pagina

Tags: reactjs, pdf, jspdf

Estoy intentando convertir html a pdf usando jspdf, pero mi problema es con el salto de linea ya que al convertirlo se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se corta justo a la mitad y no en mi html si le tengo colocado para que haga un salto

```
tr{
   page-break-inside: avoid;
}
table{
   page-break-inside: auto;
}
```

Por lo que no se que estoy haciendo mal en este caso o si hay que agregar alguna propiedad mas?, ya que en mi jspdf lo tengo de la siguiente forma:

```
const doc = new jsPDF({
    format: [816, 1056],
    unit: 'px',
    userUnit: 96
});
doc.html(response.data, {
    html2canvas: {
        allowTaint: true,
        letterRendering: true,
        logging: true,
        width: 1020,
        scale: 1
    },
    callback: (doc) => {
        doc.save("test.pdf");
        setLoadingPrint(false)
        Swal.close()
    },
    autoPaging: 'slice',
    margin: [5, 20, 15, 20]
})
```

Estoy usando `jspdf 2.5.1` y estoy usando react, entonces no se si hay que configurar algo mas?